# Why does Themes.pas leak the TThemeServices singleton when linked into a DLL

Tags: delphi

**Update:**  The changes to introduce VCL styles in XE2 have removed the memory leak. So I guess it was unintentional after all.

---

I came across a VCL memory leak today, in Themes.pas. It only occurs for DLLs. The unit finalization code is as so:

```
finalization
  if not IsLibrary then
    InternalServices.Free;
```

`InternalServices` is a singleton that is created on demand when you call the `ThemeServices` function. Many DLLs do not have UI and so do not ever create this singleton. However, I happen to have a COM add-in to Excel which does result in this leak manifesting.

The leak doesn't particularly bother me because this DLL is never repeatedly loaded and unloaded from the same process. And I know how I could fix the leak using the `ThemeServicesClass` global variable.

My question though, is to ask if anyone can explain why this code is the way it is. It seems quite deliberately coded this way. For the life of me I cannot come up with an explanation for this intentional leak.

Comment: It's got several QC reports with status open: 90368, 84990, 66013

Comment: @Sertac You know I was planning to submit a QC report if I couldn't come up with an explanation. The code just seemed so intentional that I didn't imagine it would be a bug and so I never considered looking on QC. I must say the responses to those QC reports are all too depressingly familiar. The submitters present the lines of VCL source code that blatantly leak, and Tomohiro Takahashi asks for a sample project to reproduce it. It puts you off submitting reports!

Comment: That, and other ways which puts you off.. I know the feeling... BTW, apparently some of the reporters/commentators has set 'IsLibrary' to false for a workaround, which makes me suspect if there's any good reason for the code at all.

Comment: @David, I've just ran into this memory leak. Do you think it is safe to just call `ThemeServices.Free` at my library's finalization part or should I rather use [`this solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032920/960757) ?

Comment: I think either would be fine. But do you really need to do anything. It's only a problem if the DLL is loaded and unloaded repeatedly.

Comment: Now thinking about it, I actually don't need to care about it. My library will be loaded just one time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One explanation is that the unit finalization section is executed while the **OS loader lock** is active. During that time, there are significant restrictions on what a DLL is allowed to do without risking deadlock.

Comment: Ah, I am aware of the issue with the loader lock, and indeed go to some trouble to work around it, but I hadn't remembered it when trying to explain this. Thanks, I'll have a look at the destructor code and see if it does anything that might be an issue.

Comment: The destructor calls `CloseThemeData` for each themed element that has been cached, and then it calls `UxTheme.FreeThemeLibrary`. I thought that might be a problem, but UxTheme is happy to call `FreeThemeLibrary` in its finalization, so that can't be it. There are no class members of managed types (e.g. interfaces).

Answer (score 5):

We run into this same problem as well. Here is what we are currently doing to prevent the leak in our projects:

1. In the dll .dpr file add Themes to the uses section.
2. Add the following to clean up the leak on shutdown:

   ```
   procedure DLLEntryProc(EntryCode: integer);
   begin
     case EntryCode of
     DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
     begin
       ThemeServices.Free;
     end;
     DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
     begin
     end;
     DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
     begin
     end;
     DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
     begin
     end;
     end;
   end;

   begin
     {$IFDEF DEBUG}
     ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown  := True;
     {$ENDIF}
     DllProc := @DLLEntryProc;
   end.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On the same idea that there must be a good reason to leave it leaking (indy leaks a couple of things on purpose as well, or at least it used to) I prefer to ignore it, like so:

```
{$I FastMM4Options.inc}
...
{$IFDEF EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
  if IsLibrary then// ThemeServices is leaked when created in a DLL.
    RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(ThemeServices);
{$ENDIF}
```